# Is there a way to set directory for certificates and provisionings downloaded by fastlane?

Tags: ios, fastlane

Currently they are downloaded to my project directory. Can I set subdirectory and tell the fastlane to download it there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `sigh` to download the profiles in your `Fastfile` - you can specify the directory. Here's an example:

```
sigh(output_path: 'path_to/Provisioning Profiles', adhoc: true, skip_certificate_verification: true)
```

Here's a link to the [sigh documentation.](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/)

Comment: That solution moves only provisioning profile, not certificate;)